# Search bar not calling textDidChange for some reason

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

I'm very new to Xcode so please excuse my ignorance.

I have a `searchBar` and a `tableView` on a ViewController. I have an `IBOutlet` for the `searchBar` and I specified `searchBar.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`. For some reason `textDidChange` is not getting called when I type in the search bar.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working. Even though I specified `searchBar.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`, it did not work until I specified the `searchBar` delegate in the storyboard interface.

Comment: how to do that?